# SharePoint 2013 - Send Calendar view by email using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, calendar, view

I have created a Leave Calendar in SharePoint 2013 and employees add their leave request on the calendar which goes through workflow approval process. I would like to send a monthly view of the leave calendar to all the employees every month using workflow.
I have created a Gnatt view on the calendar and if monthly view is not possible, Gantt view will also do.

Comment: are you trying to send a copy of the calendar view / gantt view itself or just a link to the view?

Comment: Copy of the Calendar view / Gantt view.. so that people on travel can see the current month leave calendar on their mobile instead of clicking on link.

Answer (score 1):

@Enigma:
Ask yourself this question:
Why not have your users use the ‘Connect to Outlook’ option to subscribe to the calendars?
[[image: Connect to Outlook]

Why not send a simple link to the users after talking to your networking resource?

Either using the ‘Connect to Outlook’ option or sending a link via email will require the same thing:
networking staff will either need to punch a hole through the firewall with a :443 connection and routing rule to your on-prem SharePoint FQDN - or have a VPN configured.  Either way, the only inconvenience a user would experience is to enter credentials once more.

Otherwise, what you are left with is a complex solution that I think is neither supportable/feasible nor possible.  And likely not availing itself to automation.  (Alternatively, you could manually screen shoot the page and send out the email manually - which would likely be just as efficient vis-a-vis what I outline below).

Either you would need to have some way of saving the actual view of the calendar as an image or somehow scraping html / css from it and inserting it into an email template and doing so consistently on a regular basis - and each time that method fails, you will get annoyed customer emails, and have to drop what you are doing and fix the issue because the aggrieved user(s) are traveling.

The only other way I can conceive of you reaching some solution approximating what you are talking about is to create a calendar in Excel, saving it to a library, and using the [Excel Rest API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/resources-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api), specifically the */model/Charts('yourChartName')?$format=image* interface or the */model/Ranges('yourNamedRange')?$format=image*  interface.

But if you are using the Excel REST API, you have to curate that *individual file* - as opposed to curating a SP list.

Either way, if you are inserting images into emails (even Base64 encoded images), your users’ Outlook clients are likely configured to block images by default....  Which brings me back to: just send a link.

You are an IT god, not them.  Use that to push back at unreasonable / infeasible requests and manage expectations.

Comment: Thanks Fritz for the detailed report. I was thinking of it its possible to get a list of holiday for the coming month and send out an email to all employees 1st working day of each month.

Answer (score 0):

Per [my research](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-email-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4), embed a calendar view in the "send email" action is not supported.

As Fritz said, Connecting to outlook and reviewing the calendar in outlook app is an easy way.

Comment: Thanks Julie. Much appreciate your advise with this. Is it possible to get a list of upcoming holiday for the next one month and add to the mail using workflow. Sorry . i am very new to SharePoint.

Comment: Same as above, I don’t think we can embed all upcoming holidays in the body of the email.

Comment: Thanks Julie. Much appreciated. I am now looking to get a powershell script to screenshot the calendar page every month and send by email. Only issue is i cant have this automated since if the screen is in locked mode,, it send the lock screen image as email. Will wait for some good solution or some new addition in future sharepoint release.